# Extend "local" storage on proxmox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, lvm, proxmox

There is Proxmox VE 3.0 with 2x1Tb HDD in mirror:

[image: Proxmox storage list]
[image: local storage] [image: backups storage]

I have 1 huge container (~430Gb), that is located in `local`. I need to:

1. extend `local` with new 2x1Tb disks.
2. **or** create new storage (with new disks) and migrate container to new storage

How it can be done without reinstalling Proxmox?
Thanks!

---

P.S. I can create new storage item as LVM, but LVM is not suitable for containers

Comment: Why LVM is not suitable for containers? I have running LXC containers on lvm and they work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

update to latest release should be fixed ;)

https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/proxmox-ve-6-2-released.69647/

Answer (score 0):

proxmox ve 3 is running on debian 7 - support ended in 2018, your system is vulnerable like hell and even if you keep it you will probably end up when you will need to install **ANY** new package - all repositories are already unavailable for some year.